# timezone change in redhat

Tags: linux, redhat

I tried to change time zone in redhat 7 from UTC to Asia/Kuala_Lumpur using command:

`#timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kuala_Lumpur`

but it shows as below:

```
[root@mykultestrhel04t ~]# timedatectl
      Local time: Thu 2019-08-22 06:41:03 UTC
  Universal time: Thu 2019-08-22 06:41:03 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2019-08-22 06:41:03
       Time zone: Asia/Kuala_Lumpur (UTC, +0000)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

I want the result to be instead as below:

`Time zone: Asia/Kuala_Lumpur (+08, +0800)`

How can I change it to `(+08, +0800)`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `TZ` environment variable. `MY` is the [timezone setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for Malaysian peninsular.

```
export TZ=MY
```

You would normally add this command in your `/etc/profile` file. `/etc/profile` is the system-wide start-up script which will apply to all system users.

Note you can **check from the shell** your correct timezone setting using the **`tzselect`** shell command. It comes handy when you want  to  know what  time  it  is in other countries, or if you just wonder what
timezones exist.